# How to OSGi with Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee, osgi

I am interested in OSGi (and very new to OSGi) and looking a way to integrate in Tomcat as my jars and other modules  can be loaded in Tomcat without restarting.  Any one let me know any source, tutorial that demonstrates step by step clear procedure ( from ground zero level) how to implement OSGi in Tomcat for war file.

Comment: maybe you should look at Eclipse Virgo - https://www.eclipse.org/virgo/

Comment: @SvetlinZarev, Thank you for your quick response. If I move with Virgo, I ll have to leave  tomcat,won't I ? I'd like to stay with tomcat (7,8) as my other apps are running in tomcat.

Comment: there is a Virgo Tomcat distribution - https://www.eclipse.org/virgo/feature-summary/

Comment: See here: https://github.com/enexusde/Karaf-Spring